# Embedded Visualforce Button to Update Field

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to have an embedded VF page show as a button on my Opportunity record that will update a custom field.  The page loads, but when I click the button, nothing happens.  Does anyone see what I am doing wrong in the page below?

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" >

<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function evp();
    {
        var opp = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
        opp.id = //set Record Id here, potentially get it from the URL ?id= param

        opp.Approval_Status__c = 'Sent to EVP';
        sforce.connection.update([opp]); 
        window.location.reload(); //to reload the window and show the updated values
    }
</script>

<apex:form>
<div style="text-align: center"><p/>

    <apex:commandButton Value="EVP Approval" onClick="evp();return false;"/>

</div>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to see yeah....

```
function evp();
```

Notice the `;` here. This one is not letting anything happen :P. Remove this and it will start working.

Also **on side note** if this is the only thing you are doing you don't need a visual force page.

You can rather use "**On click javascript**" and put javascript code there. Like this:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")} 

var opp = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
opp.id = '{!Opportunity.Id}'
opp.name = 'Sent to EVP';
sforce.connection.update([opp]); 
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: Thanks.  The semi-colon was the culprit.  Looking to hard at it I guess!  Thanks so much!

Comment: BTW, I am using an embedded VF page because I want to have the buttons in a different spot on the page layout instead of at the top with the other buttons.